# Creation of tag [abram]

Tags: discussion, tags

I was wondering... considering Abraham lived as Abram up until certain point, does it make sense to create a tag "Abram" to speak of questions regarding pre-covenant time and specify in "Abraham"' tag description that it's to use for pos-covenant time questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this would not be an appropriate tag. We should have only one tag per individual. Consider that we don't have separate tags for "peter", "simon-peter", "apostle-peter", "st-peter", "cephas", etc.

Comment: This is true, but I don't mind adding it as a synonym.   I don't think I'd want [tag:simon] as a synonym for [tag:peter] though.

Comment: @Peter Oh yes synonyms are great as long as they're not overly ambiguous.